# Numerical solution of PDE with nonstandard boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I wonder if Mathematica can handle following pde in two-dimension
[image]

I have tried following but got errors.

[image]

I need numerical solution of the problem on line y equal to zero.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The best way is to solve it with hand made code based on FDM.

Comment: Hi, indeed I have a hand made solution obtained via a collocation method and I wanted to compare this solution with a reference solution.

Comment: See solution with iterative method. Could you show your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try an iterative solution using `NestList`

```
sol = NestList[
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
u[x, 0] == 1/2 Integrate[#[x, y], {y, 1/2, 2}], 
u[x, 2] == Sin[Pi x],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 0 || x == 1]}, u, 
Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]]] &, 0 &, 10] // Quiet

Plot3D[ sol[[-1]] [x, y] , Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]],PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Iteration converges quite well

```
Plot3D[ sol[[-2 ]][x, y] - sol[[-1 ]][x, y],Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and fullfills the inetgral-bc

```
Plot[{sol[[-1]][x , 0],1/2 NIntegrate[sol[[-1]][x , yy], {yy, 1/2,2}]}, {x, 0, 1},PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice method (+1). Is this reference solution what author looking for?

Comment: Yes, this solution is almost same with my solution.

Comment: @Merakli You have a solution too nad didn't show it?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you for your solution. As I previously stated I have another solution obtained via another numerical method. The method is hand made, little long and not implemented in Mathematica so I did not need to show it.

Answer (score 4):

Solution with iterative method in a loop

```
U[0][x_, y_] := Sin[Pi  x] Exp[- Pi  y];

Do[U[i] = 
   NDSolveValue[{f = 
      Interpolation[
       Table[{x, 
         NIntegrate[U[i - 1][x, y], {y, 1/2, 2}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
          PrecisionGoal -> 4]}, {x, 0, 1, .1}]]; 
     Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, u[0, y] == 0, u[1, y] == 0, 
     u[x, 2] == Sin[Pi x], u[x, 0] == 1/2  f[x]}, 
    u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}];, {i, 1, 10}]
```

Visualization

```
{Plot[Evaluate[Table[U[i][x, 0], {i, 1, n}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[U[n][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", PlotRange -> All, MeshStyle -> White]}
```

[image: Figure 1]